# How do you reuse code in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, function, angular2-directives, angular-factory

I have controller which fetches some data and adds some extra items based on the information. The information should be searchable. I have working code for that now, but was wondering what is the best way to reuse the code? Is it directives? factory? Here is the code :

```
app.controller('searchProducts', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.search = function(val) {
    $scope.val = val;
    //from here
    let query;
    if(!$scope.val) {
        query = BASE_URL+"Products";   
    }
    if($scope.val) {
        query = encodeURI("Products?$filter=contains(ProductName,\'"+val+"\')");
        query = BASE_URL+query;
    }
    $http.get(query)
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.rawData = response.data;
            angular.forEach($scope.rawData.value, function(value) {
                //looping the data, replacing the IDs with actual data from the source
                //Getting actual Supplier using SupplierID
                $http.get("http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Suppliers("+value.SupplierID+")/CompanyName/$value")
                    .then(function(response) {
                        value.Supplier = response.data;           
               })
                //Getting actual Category using CategoryID
                $http.get("http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories("+value.CategoryID+")/CategoryName/$value")
                    .then(function(response) {
                        value.Category = response.data;           
               })
            });
        })
    //to here
}
    //is repeated here
});
```

Comment: make a service or factoriy for your http calls.

Comment: I tried creating a service, but are having some problems with including it in my controller. The code for that is here: https://pastebin.com/xc9MW081

Comment: It will work better if you [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) the  $http promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a factory and bundle that behavior in one or more methods, i.e.

```
app.factory('myFactory', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        myRequest: function(query) {
            return $http.get(query).then(this.myHandler);
        },
        myHandler: function(response) {
            var categoryPromises = [];
            var supplierPromises = [];
            angular.forEach(response.data, function(value) {
                supplierPromises.push($http.get("http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Suppliers("+value.SupplierID+")/CompanyName/$value"));
                categoryPromises.push($http.get("http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories("+value.CategoryID+")/CategoryName/$value"));
            });
            return $q.all([$q.all(supplierPromises), $q.all(valuePromises)]);
        }
    };
});
// and to invoke the factory
app.controller('myController', function(myFactory) {
    myFactory.myRequest('/path/to/resource')
        .then(function(results) {
            //... handle your results
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            throw e;
        });
});
```